# Can't find VisualStudio linker LINK.EXE

Tags: visual-studio, linker, opencl, intel-fpga

I'm following the openCl documentation provided by Altera to setup an FPGA board and run an example on it. So far I have installed the SDK and followed the instructions but when I get to the step where I have to compile the kernel, I get the following error:

> Error: aoc: Can't find VisualStudio linker LINK.EXE.
>       Either use Visual Studio x64 Command Prompt or run %ALTERAOCLSDKROOT%\init_opencl.bat to setup your environment.

So I tried running the init_opencl.bat script but I get the following message:

> AOCL_BOARD_PACKAGE_ROOT path is not set in environment
>       Setting to default s5_ref board.
>       If you want to target another board, do
>       set AOCL_BOARD_PACKAGE_ROOT=board_pkg_dir and re-run this script
>
> VisualStudio's link.exe is not on the path. Guessing its location.
>       Cannot find VisualStudio installation by looking at the environment.
>       If VisualStudio is installed, use VisualStudio Command Prompt to set all
>       required environment variables.

Here is a link to the documentation I am trying to follow:

https://documentation.altera.com/#/00016207-AA$NT00067143

I also tried adding link.exe to the environment variables path but that had no luck. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\link.exe).

Comment: Did you add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\ ` to the path? I hope you didn't add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\link.exe` which is a file

Comment: I added C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\link.exe. Is it suppose to be bin?

Comment: You don't add file names to the path. Just directory names that will be searched for files. So it should be something like C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\  (and yes, in this case I believe link.exe is inside `bin`

Comment: It worked, it was just that issue. Thank you!