# Unable to Find LINK.EXE in Visual Studio Installation

Tags: visual-studio, linker, visual-studio-2022

I've recently installed the "Desktop development with C++" workload in Visual Studio, but I'm encountering difficulty locating the LINK.EXE executable. I've checked the installation directory, and it seems to be missing or in an unexpected location.

[image: image4]

[image: image3]

[image: image2]

[image: image1]

[cant find visualstudio linker link exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37819783/cant-find-visualstudio-linker-link-exe)